# Cannot find where a local server is coming from

Tags: ubuntu, networking

So a while ago I found the source code for Cookie Clicker and was using it as a 'Hello World' for some server testing I was doing at the time. However just today I accidentally went to `http://127.0.0.1` instead of `http://127.0.0.1:8080`. When I did, Cookie Clicker showed up for a few seconds until my browser froze up and killed the page. I am confused, given that I have restarted my laptop several dozen times since the aforementioned tests, and I am reasonably confident that I've reinstalled Ubuntu and restored from backup since then too. Any idea where this server is coming from?

[image: Locally hosted Cookie Clicker]

Comment: Does `http://127.0.0.1:8080` still work? You only have the problem when you're trying to get `http://127.0.0.1` loaded? Please [edit] your question and add the output of the following command on the server: `lsof -P -i:80,8080`

Comment: Use of language here is a bit confused. The server is inside the machine you are looking at. You can see the server pid/name using any of lsof, ss or netstat (as root). The specific options for each of these are in your man pages.